# How to use immutable object without operator=() in procedural code

Tags: c++, constants, immutability

Given an immutable C++ object (its members are `const`, which means its `operator=()` method does not exist), how do you implement this simple procedural pattern (which would require `Object::operator=()` to exist):

```
Object someObject {17};

// ...

if (...) {
   someObject = Object {42};
}

// ...

use(someObject);
```

Comment: `Object someObject2 = (...) ? Object{42} : someObject;`?

Comment: Are you asking for a workaround to change an object that is not assignable??

Comment: Two variations on the suggestion by @immibis: `use((...) ? Object{42} : someObject);`, or `Object someObject{(...) ? 42 : 17}; use(someObject);`

Comment: Obviously this is a simplification of the problem. My code is more complicated than that and has more conditions where the "current" object (`someObject`) can be changed (and also other stuff is happening in those conditions). This would multiply the ternaries like crazy and repeat the conditions at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My pattern in such a situation is to extract initialization code into a function:

```
Object ini(...){
      if(...) {
            return Object{42};
      }
      return Object{17};
}
.....
Object someObject=ini(...);// copy constructor used (or not, because of RVO)
use(someObject);
```

If initialization is simple you could use:

```
Object someObject = ...? Object{42} : Object{17};
```

It is not very different to declaring your `o`-variable const.

---

If the `someObject=17` is used and then replaced with `someObject=42` - it's just undermining the good intentions which were pursued by declaring some members const.

There are two alternatives:

1. declaring some members `const` was not such bright idea - it can be undone and  an assigment operator can be added.
2. using `Object`  as it was meant to be used.

What should not be done lightly: making some tricks with pointers/references - it will just make your code more complex as it is. Better to use a new variable if needed:

```
Object someObject {17};

// ...

Object newSomeObject = ... ? Object {42} : someObject {17};  
use(newSomeObject);
```

In the case that copying of the old object could be a performance problem, the code can be refactored in such a way, that

```
use(need42(..) ? create42() : object17);
```

can be used without copying data. This solution assumes that `use` uses a const reference of its argument or the parameter is passed by-value.

---

In my opinion every change of an immutable object should yield a new object, otherwise, the following can happen:

```
ImmutableObject obj(1);
ImmutableObject &ref=obj;//ref.member=1
...
obj=ImmutableObject(2);
//ref.member!=1, that is puzzling, I assumed ref to be immutable!
```

Now, the user of your object (via `ref`) gets irritated because the object was changed! The whole point of the immutability is that you can reason, that the values **never ever** change. If they can change, there is not that many advantages in using "immutables" in the first place.

Comment: I guess you should remove the `if` block in your last example. Like I wrote in one of my question's comments, there could be other branches that need to replace the immutable object with another one. Knowing this, it becomes near impossible to use a combination of ternaries. Your initialization pattern would be fine, but other stuff is happening in those conditions, not just the replacement of the immutable object. In the end, I think the best point of your answer is that maybe I _need_ `operator=()` after all...

Comment: Is the object still considered immutable with an `operator=()`? IMO, as long as you modify all its members at once (by copying them from another object of the same type) and they remain consistent and valid, I have no problem calling this immutable.

Comment: @eepp You have to stay pragmatic: if the price for immutability is efficiency (more copying might be needed) or major refactoring and you are not ready to pay this price - maybe it is not the right place/right time for immutability (yet).

Comment: @eepp I also don't think that calling an object immutable and then changing it is a nice thing, please see my last edit for some elaboration.

Comment: Yes I understand. Maybe _immutable_ is not the right term then.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to use shared_ptr.

```
shared_ptr<Object> someObject(new  Object(17));
shared_ptr<Object> anotherObject(new Object(42));
// ...

if (...) {

   someObject = anotherObject;
}

use(someObject);
```

Comment: A `shared_ptr` is complete overkill here. A `unique_ptr` would be better (but is still overkill).

Comment: Please use a `std::unique_ptr` instead, `std::shared_ptr` is overkill.

Comment: This seems a bit heavy and it's not necessary to use the heap for this purpose. Why not just having two named `Object` objects on the stack, and using a local, non-const pointer to modify the pointed one and then do `use(*chosenObject);` instead? No heap needed. I still find this heavy though, and we're creating two `Object` objects even if we only needed one (in some cases) at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers work when your initialization logic may be simple, but if you're detangling some spaghetti code, this *might* help.

If it isn't, take from java (they might not have invented it, but I see java programmers use this most) -- the builder pattern. Here are two possible ways of implementing it in `C++`.

```
#include <string>

class ImmutableClass {
 public:
  ImmutableClass(int a, int b, std::string c) : a_(a), b_(b), c_(c) {}
  // Getters...
 private:
  ImmutableClass& operator=(const ImmutableClass&) = delete;
  const int& GetA() {return a_;}
  const int& GetB() {return b_;}
    const std::string& GetC() {return c_;}
    const int a_;
    const int b_;
    const std::string c_;
};

struct ImmutableClassBuilderExampleOne {
 public:
  // Note the default initialization to avoid undefined behavior.
  int a = 0;
  int b = 0;
  std::string c;
};
// Less boilerplate, less encapsulation, if that's your thing.
ImmutableClass BuildImmutableClass(const ImmutableClassBuilderExampleOne& icb) {
    return ImmutableClass(icb.a, icb.b, icb.c);
}

// More boilerplate, more encapsulation, can be "tidied" with macros.
class ImmutableClassBuilderExampleTwo {
 public:
  const ImmutableClass build() {
    return ImmutableClass(a_, b_, c_);
  }
  ImmutableClassBuilderExampleTwo& setA(const int a) {
    a_ = a; 
    return *this;
  }
  ImmutableClassBuilderExampleTwo& setB(const int b) {
    b_ = b; 
    return *this;
  }
  ImmutableClassBuilderExampleTwo& setC(const std::string& c) {
    c_ = c; 
    return *this;
  }
 private:
  // Note the default initialization to avoid undefined behavior.
  int a_ = 0;
  int b_ = 0;
  std::string c_;
};
```

Comment: With all due respect, this looks horrendous

Comment: When you need it to provide a more normal wrapper over some legacy code, it's useful. I personally avoid the pattern, but when it's needed, it's appreciated. `BuilderExample2().SetA(1).SetB(2).SetC("").build()` (with some conditional value resetting in-between) may be much cleaner than some other hacks to get what you want.

Comment: I appreciate the solution and see the point. I believe it is similar in a way to [this solution](http://martin-moene.blogspot.ca/2012/08/growing-immutable-value.html), in which I would have a mutable `ObjectData` which I can modify, and use it to build a final, immutable `Object` when I need it (in my example, this would be `use(Object {objectData});`. This could work, but I'm interested in other approaches too.